# Round Robin em Python usando a Lib Threading

Tags: python, thread, multithreading, biblioteca, processo

O código tem o intuito de testar tempo de processamento e quantidade de execuções de 3 diferentes processos em um sistema **Round Robin** com diferentes unidades de tempo como quantum!

Basicamente, a ideia é que existem 3 processos indiferentes, cada um precisando de uma quantidade diferente de tempo para executar. Preciso fazer um sistema utilizando o princípio Round Robin (cada um executa pela quantidade de tempo especificada pelo quantum, em fila, até que seja executado 100%, com os processos que já foram executados saindo da fila).

Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Descobri a biblioteca Threading que existe com o intuito de executar diferentes threads ao "mesmo tempo". Utilizando o `.join()` desta biblioteca, cada threading só executa quando a anterior é finalizada.

Este é o código que eu tenho até agora:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import threading
from datetime import *
import time

process1tamanho = 0
process2tamanho = 0
process3tamanho = 0
valoresDeQuantum = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]

def processo1():
    global process1tamanho
    global calc

    while (True):
        process1tamanho = process1tamanho + 1
        calc = 2 * 2
        if process1tamanho == 100000:
            break

def processo2():
    global process2tamanho
    global calc

    while (True):
        process2tamanho = process2tamanho + 1
        calc = 2 * 2
        if process2tamanho == 100000:
            break

def processo3():
    global process3tamanho
    global calc

    while (True):
        process3tamanho = process3tamanho + 1
        calc = 2 * 2
        if process3tamanho == 100000:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = threading.Thread(target=processo1, args=())
    x.start()
    x.join()

    x = threading.Thread(target=processo2, args=())
    x.start()
    x.join()

    x = threading.Thread(target=processo3, args=())
    x.start()
    x.join()
```

No caso, o array `valoresDeQuantum` serve para definir os 4 valores de quantum dos quais preciso usar para executar o código e analisar os resultados em diferentes medidas de tempo (1ms, 10ms, 100ms e 1 segundo).

Comment: Não peça ajuda, vá direto ao problema. Muitas possíveis perguntas boas são estragadas porque as pessoas querem parecer humildes.